# Regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need regular expression (C#) for symbol * - it should match any number of any characters, but it can contain only one space. I tried following, but its not working:

```
 @".*[^[\t\0x0020]^[\t\0x0020]+].*"
 @".*[^\s^\s+].*"
 @".*[^\s\s+].*"
```

any way how to create regex like this?

Example: If user write expression `MTN*-*` it has to match for example

```
MTN3111-0000
```

but not

```
MTN311100  MTN3111-0000
```

Comment: could you make an example of a passing and failing input?

Comment: `[^\s]` matches the character not in the specified set of characters.

Comment: You say it is for the character `-`, but then mention one space.  However you matching example does not have any spaces.  I'm not sure I understand what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this expression:

```
\S*\s?\S*
```

It would match any number of any characters, but allow at most one space.

Comment: @Gian, no, OP doesn't want to anchor it, as it will be used a part of larger expressions. And also note that your expression would allow two spaces in the target string, try to figure out why. ;-)

Comment: Ok. About my expression, when I test it I don't manage to match a good result when 2 spaces are entered, are you sure of what you are saying?

Comment: @Gian, yes, I'm sure. Hint: It has something to do with one of the two characters you added, look it up in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions).

Comment: I was thinking of the carriage return, but in my app, I can't have a space and a carriage return with this regexp =/

Comment: @Gian, the string `" \n"` will match. `$` always allows a `\n` at the end of string.

Comment: Maybe my app is not well designed, but when I enter a space and a carraige return (hitting enter), no match is found. Well, never mind :)

Comment: On windows enter is not `"\n"`, it's `"\r\n"`. Set the string directly, and then try to match it.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
@"[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*"
```

Then there may be some specifics depending on other requirements

Answer (score 0):

here try this:

```
([^\-]+\-[^\s]+)\s
```